# How to add users from a text file and generate a random password Fedora

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

I am trying to add users from a text file, but not just adding the users I also need to add them to a group, specify their home directory and then generate a random password that gets sent to a system admin.

I have found a number of examples of adding users from a text file that is to be read but it doesn't have all the facets I am trying to include.

I have tried using awk in order to read through the file which has the format

```
Firstname1 Group1  /home/Username1 Firstname1 Lastname1
Firstname2  Group1  /home/Username2 Firstname2 Lastname2
Firstname3  Group2  /home/Username3 Firstname3 Lastname3
```

The Firstname becomes the username each field is separately by two double spaces.

I am getting lost with all the arguments I have to add in order to take each field and attach a variable to it which has been read from the file and then generate the random password that goes along with it!

```
#!/bin/bash
file=newusers.txt
username = awk -F"  "  '{print $1}' newusers.txt
gid = awk -F"  "  '{print $2}' newusers.txt 
home-dir = awk -F"  "  '{print $3}' newusers.txt 
adduser -d $username $gid $home-dir
```

I am not getting anywhere with just adding the users from the file I am trying to read at this point.

Comment: cut/paste your script into https://shellcheck.net and fix all the errors it finds. If that doesn't solve your problem then post a new Q. Good luck.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: `pwgen` or `genpassword` (a Perl script from some package) or https://itsfoss.com/password-generators-linux/

Comment: use python. Create a script to parse each line of the file and run adduser. you could use subprocess for this. and if you google there will be tools to generate passwords. you can take an idea here https://pynative.com/python-generate-random-string/

Answer (score -1):

Your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

username=$(awk '{print $1}' newusers.txt)
gid=$(awk '{print $2}' newusers.txt)
homedir=$(awk '{print $3}' newusers.txt)
adduser -d "$username" "$gid" "$homedir"
```

Assume newuser.txt's content is:

`user group home`

Comment: @shellter script modified .. Thanks

Comment: Good show! Think about how you can reduce your code to one call to `awk`. Search for `[bash] while read` for some ideas. Good luck.

Comment: (I didn't downvote your answer), but I bet whoever did doesn't like 3 calls to an external program when one will do. Yes, this case is trivial, and 3 calls is not the end of the world, but it sets bad habits that can slow down your processing time significantly when you have a project that requires you process a file with 100,000s of data elements. Good luck.

Comment: to make it one line would you use 
awk -F "  " username= $1, gid=$2, homedir=$3 newuserst.txt